# PHP_SELF vs url of same page

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

I am trying to make my code more clear using the include function of php. I am using the same part of code in three of my pages but the one of this pages is the same page that i call when I execute this part of the code. So can I instead of

```
action="<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>"
```

to use the link of this page(action="thispage.php")? Also in order to use include the code has to be exactly the same? I mean I have parts of my code that are almost the same only some small things change. Such as in each page I have a css style that I apply in the selected link. Is there any way to change some things of the code included? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, you could. Although a much simpler way would be to use `action=""` when it's on a form. The empty string tells the browser to submit the form to the page you're currently on.

When you're including a file, it is actually included into your code, so it "inherits" all of the variables inside the current scope. You can define a variable inside your file and then use that variable inside a conditional in the other file to determine what exactly it's supposed to do.

Answer (score 0):

Well you could make a function that you can pass a number of parameters to:

```
function include_partial($path, $options = array()) {
    extract($options); // import array keys as local variables
    include($file);
}

// usage
include_partial('/path/to/file', array('action' => $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
```

Of course you can do the same thing without the function jsut set the varibles in the file you are including from:

```
$action = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
include('/path/to/file');
```

What i like about the function is it allows you to scope the variables so you arent continually using global scope for things.